# Create foreign key that references to composite key

Tags: sql-server, database, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key, composite-key

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
    PersonID int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    PersonName nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
    PersonSurname nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (PersonID)
)

CREATE TABLE Author
(
    AuthorID int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    PersonID int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (AuthorID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Person(PersonID)
)

CREATE TABLE Supervisor 
(
    SupervisorID int NOT NULL ,
    PersonID int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SupervisorID,PersonID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Person(PersonID)
)

CREATE TABLE University
(
    UniversityID int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    UniversityName nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (UniversityID)
)

CREATE TABLE Enstitute
(
    EnstituteID int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    UniversityID int NOT NULL,
    EnstituteName nvarchar(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (EnstituteID),
    FOREIGN KEY (UniversityID) REFERENCES University(UniversityID)
)

CREATE TABLE Thesis 
(
    ThesisNo numeric(8,0) NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    AuthorID int NOT NULL,
    EnstituteID int NOT NULL,
    SupervisorID int NOT NULL,
    Title nvarchar(100)NOT NULL,
    Abstract nvarchar(500)NOT NULL,
    Pages int NOT NULL,
    SubmitDate datetime NOT NULL,
    [Type] nchar(30) NOT NULL,
    [Language] nchar(20) NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (ThesisNo),
    FOREIGN KEY (EnstituteID) REFERENCES Enstitute(EnstituteID),
    FOREIGN KEY (AuthorID) REFERENCES Author(AuthorID),
    FOREIGN KEY (SupervisorID) REFERENCES Supervisor(SupervisorID)
)

CREATE TABLE Keywords
(
    ThesisNo numeric(8,0) NOT NULL,
    Keyword nvarchar(50) NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (ThesisNo) REFERENCES Thesis(ThesisNo)
)

CREATE TABLE Subjects
(
    SubjectID int NOT NULL,
    ThesisNo numeric(8,0) NOT NULL,
    [Subject] nvarchar(120) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SubjectID),
    FOREIGN KEY (ThesisNo) REFERENCES Thesis(ThesisNo) 
)
```

I get this error:

> Msg 1767, Level 16, State 0, Line 38
> Foreign key 'FK__Thesis__AuthorID__47DBAE45' references invalid table 'Author'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 38
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors

[image: this is part of the diagram I want to do.]

Comment: Use semicolons to terminate statements

Comment: `Thesis` has a FK to `Supervisor`, but the PK in `Supervisor` has two columns - if you want to reference that with a FK, you **MUST** provide both columns in the child table as well. You can **NOT** reference only part of a PK - either all of it (every single column of it), or you cannot reference it.

Comment: I tried this :  FOREIGN KEY (SupervisorID) REFERENCES Supervisor(SupervisorID , PersonID) but this is not work. Happened an error. @marc_s

Comment: The foreign key side would also need to be two columns. However in this instance it's easier just to make `Supervisor` a single column both primary and foreign key (to `Person`)

Answer (score 1):

Why does Supervisor have a compound key.  It looks like a subtype of Person, and should share the same key structure.  eg

```
CREATE TABLE Supervisor 
(
    PersonID int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (PersonID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Person(PersonID)
)
```

Author too

```
CREATE TABLE Author
(
    PersonID int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (PersonID ),
    FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Person(PersonID)
)
```

Although it's often better to just have a Person table.

Comment: I have homework and some of the rules are:
2. A person can be author of more than one theses (for example, a person can prepare a Master thesis, later s/he can prepare a Doctorate thesis),
3. A thesis can have only one author (unlike scientific papers, there is no co-authorship in theses),
4. A thesis must have at least one supervisor,
5. A thesis can have at most two supervisors (one supervisor, and one co-supervisor),
6. A person can supervise many theses

So, I think  for creating 2 supervisor I used composite key but I think it is mistake.What sould I do..

Comment: You don't need seperate Author or Supervisor tables for any of that.

Comment: You say I just need to create a person table? If I do that, to show relationships I need 2 relationship connection in diagram right?(between thesis and person).

Comment: @vikbaris Only if a thesis can have an undefined number of supervisors. In our case you can just create two columns on `Thesis`: `Supervisor` and `Co-supervisor`, although if you are **at all** likely to have more than that then I would make a join table like you say.

Comment: ```Thiesis``` :```Supervisor``` ```Co-Supervisor```(optional ,can be null) and ```Author``` these create from ```Person```